# Stata: Reshaping dataset – bringing variable labels to variable values

Tags: stata

I have a dataset containing different product values generated in each simulation, with the following layout:

```
+------------+-------+-------+-------+
| simulation |  v1   |  v2   |  v3   |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+
|          1 | 0,500 | 0,400 | 0,300 |
|          2 | 0,900 | 0,800 | 0,800 |
|          3 | 0,100 | 0,200 | 0,300 |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The variable names v1, v2, v3 are labelled as product ids and are not displayed at the header of the dataset. I need to reshape this dataset to long format so it would like this:

```
+------------+----+----------+-------+
| simulation | id |  label   | value |
+------------+----+----------+-------+
|          1 | v1 | 01020304 | 0,500 |
|          1 | v2 | 01020305 | 0,400 |
|          1 | v3 | 01020306 | 0,300 |
|          2 | v1 | 01020304 | 0,900 |
|          2 | v2 | 01020305 | 0,800 |
|          2 | v3 | 01020306 | 0,800 |
|          3 | v1 | 01020304 | 0,100 |
|          3 | v2 | 01020305 | 0,200 |
|          3 | v3 | 01020306 | 0,300 |
+------------+----+----------+-------+
```

The standard code `reshape long v , i(simulation) j(_count)` is not applicable in this case, as I need to reshape the variable labels and keep them in the dataset as variable values. Was wondering if there exists a way to make this kind of transposition with variable labels?

Comment: Where does the variable `label` come from? More generally, this isn't a site in which  how do I do X in language Y is a standard question. You are expected to show your own code attempts, and it's not enough to say `reshape` doesn't do what you want. Beginner questions are fine at www.statalist.org, but not here. Hint: Look at `stack` as well and http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/apply-labels-after-reshape/index.html. In short, there's documentation you are not looking at.

Comment: I understand the first part now about the variable `label`.

Comment: Hi! my dataset readily comes with labelled variables which are created automatically when transferred to Stata from .dat format. Thank you for pointing out the relevant reference to me and I will try to be more precise in my next posts.

Comment: I needed a second look at your example to guess that the variable `label` would have to come from the variable labels. Note that "labelled variable" is ambiguous as it could mean variable labels or value labels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only one idea seems needed here. If your variable labels would otherwise disappear, save them in a local macro before a `reshape` and then apply them as value labels afterwards. The FAQ cited earlier gives the flavour.

Sandpit to play in:

```
input simulation   v1     v2     v3   

    simulat~n         v1         v2         v3
1. 1  0.500  0.400  0.300 
2. 2  0.900  0.800  0.800 
3. 3  0.100  0.200  0.300 
4. end 

label var v1 "01020304"
label var v2 "01020305"
label var v3 "01020306"
```

Sample code:

```
forval j = 1/3 { 
    local labels `labels' `j' "`: var label v`j''"
} 


reshape long v, i(simulation)  
(note: j = 1 2 3)

Data                               wide   ->   long
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of obs.                        3   ->       9
Number of variables                   4   ->       3
j variable (3 values)                     ->   _j
xij variables:
                               v1 v2 v3   ->   v
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

rename v value 
label def label `labels' 
rename _j label
gen id = label 
label val label label  


list 

     +----------------------------------+
     | simula~n      label   value   id |
     |----------------------------------|
  1. |        1   01020304      .5    1 |
  2. |        1   01020305      .4    2 |
  3. |        1   01020306      .3    3 |
  4. |        2   01020304      .9    1 |
  5. |        2   01020305      .8    2 |
     |----------------------------------|
  6. |        2   01020306      .8    3 |
  7. |        3   01020304      .1    1 |
  8. |        3   01020305      .2    2 |
  9. |        3   01020306      .3    3 |
     +----------------------------------+
```